# How Should i get validation errors with sequelize and passport on login

Tags: node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js

i'm already set validate in User Model.
My Route Code is like this where I'm trying for validate.

```
var express = require('express');
var loginRouter = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../app/models/model')().User;

module.exports = function() {

    var loginController = require('../controller/loginController')();

    loginRouter.get('/login',loginController.getLogin);
    loginRouter.post('/login',
        function (req, res, next) {

            User.validate().success(function () {
              next(); // only call next if validation passes
            }).error(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              res.redirect('/auth/login');
              // or res.send({error: true}) or res.redner( ... )
            })

        },
        passport.authenticate('local-login',{   
                successRedirect: '/dashboard',
                failureRedirect: '/auth/login',
                failureFlash : true
            }
        ));

    return loginRouter;
```

### };

User.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var attributes = {
    username:
    {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'username',
        validate: {
            notNull: true,
        }
    },
    password:
    {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'password',
        validate: {
            notNull: true,
        }
    }
}

var options = {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
}

module.exports.attributes = attributes;
module.exports.options = options;
```

model.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize')
    config = require('../../config/config').database;

module.exports = function(){

    var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database,config.username,config.password,config.options);

    var UserMeta = require('./User');
    var User = sequelize.define('users',UserMeta.attributes,UserMeta.options);

    return {
        User: User
    }
};
```

---

so i don't know what i'm doing wrong here or which thing i forgot.
so any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

That's almost good, the only thing you should know is when you call `next()`, express will pass the request to the next handler, which is passportjs authentication function.

You can do as you wish with `req` and `res`. If the request does not pass the validation criteria, you can send errors or render a another page, like a normal response. But do not call `next()` in those cases.

Depending on your implementation, your code might look like this:

```
loginRouter.post('/login',
    function (req, res, next) {
        //here to get validation error
        User.validate().success(function () {
          next(); // only call next if validation passes
        }).error(function () {
          res.redirect('/auth/login');
          // or res.send({error: true}) or res.redner( ... )
        })
    },
    passport.authenticate('local-login',{   
            successRedirect: '/dashboard',
            failureRedirect: '/auth/login',
            failureFlash : true
        }
    ));
```

Comment: not woking i got this error " TypeError: User.validate is not a function ". i'm using sequelize v3.15.1 .

Comment: @utsav Can you update your question with that part of your code that you defined user?

Comment: @utsav How do you validate the user? calling `.validate()`?

Comment: OK I'm updated code how I'm trying to validate it. and thank you for your support.